# Karnaugh map minimalizer for at least 6 variables

Tags: gratis, automation, scientific-computing

Are there some good Karnaugh map minimalization software that fulfills the following:

- Can work with at least 6 variables. The more variables the better
- Free to use
- It should graphically show the Karnaugh map with the prime implicants
- Output the canonical sum-of-products or product-of-sums expressions

Comment: Why do you want this?
Karnaugh maps become super awkward for more than 4 variables.
Because they become more than 2D (but you can squeeze them onto paper).

but I assume you are going to do something with the output.
K-Maps are a means to an end, not an end in and of themselves.